# Failed to deploy multi-containers docker to ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to deploy multi containers docker into Elastic Beanstalk. But it doesn't work. I tried running on local by using the docker-compose it is working.

Below is my Dockerrun.aws.json and docker-compose.yml

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
   nginx:
      image: nginx:alphine
      restart: always
      ports:
      - 80:80
      volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      depends_on:
      - sbapi
   db:
      image: mysql:latest
      environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sbapi
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      ports:
      - 3306:3306
      restart: always
      volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
   sbapi:
      image: sbapi
      build:
         context: ./
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
      - 8080:8080
      restart: always
      volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      depends_on:
      - db
      
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
 {
   "AWSEBDockerrunVersion":2,
   "containerDefinitions":[
      {
         "name":"db",
         "hostname": "db",
         "image":"mysql:latest",
         "essential":true,
         "memory":512,
         "environment": [
            {
                "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                "value": "P@ssw0rd"
            },
            {
                "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
                "value": "sbapi"
            },
            {
                "name": "MYSQL_USER",
                "value": "user"
            },
            {
                "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
                "value": "password"
            }
         ],
         "portMappings":[
            {
               "hostPort":3306,
               "containerPort":3306
            }
         ],
         "mountPoints":[
            {
               "containerPath":"/var/lib/mysql",
               "sourceVolume":"mysql-data"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"sbapi",
         "hostname": "sbapi",
         "essential":true,
         "image":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sbapi",
         "memory":512,
         "portMappings":[
            {
               "hostPort":8080,
               "containerPort":8080
            }
         ],
         "links": [
            "db"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"nginx",
         "image":"nginx:alpine",
         "essential":true,
         "memory": 128,
         "portMappings":[
            {
               "hostPort":80,
               "containerPort":80
            }
         ],
         "mountPoints":[
            {
               "containerPath":"/etc/nginx/conf.d",
               "sourceVolume":"nginx-data"
            }
         ],
         "links":[
            "sbapi"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "family": "",
   "volumes":[
      {
         "host":{},
         "name":"mysql-data"
      },
      {
         "name": "nginx-data",
         "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/nginx/conf.d"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my nginx.stouterr.log. Not sure will it will auto shutdown.

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.1
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.14.238-125.422.amzn1.x86_64
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 133489:133489
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 30#30: gracefully shutting down
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 30#30: exiting
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 30#30: exit
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 31#31: gracefully shutting down
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 31#31: exiting
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 31#31: exit
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 30
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: worker process 30 exited with code 0
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: worker process 31 exited with code 0
2021/08/26 00:21:11 [notice] 1#1: exit
```

I checked the ECS, at first, 3 containers are running. But later on, all status changed to stopped and it spawns another new task again.

I also get the error "connection refused" to connect the MySQL from my spring boot application.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

This is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/sbapi?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

server.port = 8080
```

I was able to access the API when running docker-compose up from local. However, when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, it doesn't work. I'm not sure which part goes wrong, and I was curious why the ECS will stop itself and respawn new task again and again?

Comment: ECS service has events tab to check for msgs. Also if a task is stopped, you can view its details in ECS console and often you can find error msg as well.

Comment: Ya I checked already, I even go into the EC2 to run the docker. Somehow I getting this error Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db: System error.

Comment: I tried docker ps  I can see the mysql is running.   59d6bf11b1ba        mysql:latest                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes                0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp

Comment: I tried exec into mysql container and check the hosts root@db:/etc# cat hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      db        <------------

Comment: Why do you use `Dockerrun.aws.json` if you have docker compose?

Comment: I want deploy into ElasticBeanstalk

Comment: Docker-compose is I tested on local.

Comment: EB supports docer-compose as well. So why not use it on EB?

Comment: Do you have any reference?

Answer (score 0):

EB's  Docker platform supports docker-compose.yml as explained in [Docker environment with Docker Compose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html):

> Create a docker-compose.yml file to deploy a Docker image from a hosted repository to Elastic Beanstalk. No other files are required if all your deployments are sourced from images in public repositories.

So you may need `Dockerrun.aws.json v3` only to [enable access to private docker registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#docker-configuration.remote-repo).

Comment: My image is in ECR. so i still need dockerrun right?

Comment: @EinnHann Access to ECR should be enabled through EB instance role. So no need to dockerrun.

Comment: Which mean inside my docker-compose I can specific the docker image in ECR ?

Comment: @EinnHann I believe so. Did you try that? Any errors?

Comment: Ya I tried. I getting this error ERROR
No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment. It complained no dockerrun.aws.json found.

Comment: @EinnHann Which EB platform version are you using?

Comment: At first, I am using multicontainer. I hit ERROR No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment. Then I changed the platform to Docker, I hit Instance deployment: Both 'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in your source bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment failed. So I think Dockerrun.aws.json is needed.

Comment: I mean, which version (number) exactly. Support for compose is new.

Comment: Platform
Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.4

Comment: @EinnHann This version supports compose. You must be doing something wrong. Please update your question with more details, such as your exact project structure and zip structure.

Comment: @EinnHann How did it go? Are you able to update the question with more details I asked for?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your bind address is correct (hostname of IP address whichever you plan to use)
2. Ensure that the JDBC port number is correct
3. Ensure the security groups are open for the associated ports
4. And surely, please validate the username and password for database

Comment: I am using this spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/sbapi?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false, so hostname is db in dockerrun.aws.js. Username and Password are correct also.

Comment: But I think the error is unable to connect the MySQL. Just I not sure which configuration goes wrong.

Comment: makes sense, that eliminates #1 and #2. can you confirm if there is basic connectivity - Like are you able to curl or ping your database? Very likely, it could be security groups (#3 mentioned above) that could be blocking it

Comment: Just curious cause it is inside multi containers, so do I still need to set the security group?

Comment: I am talking about the Database, I am assuming this is an instance running on AWS and it would require Security groups 3306, 80 others to be allowed.